# App store is completely blank on MacOS catalina

Tags: catalina, mac-appstore, bug

The macOS app store completely hangs after opening i've googled for a while but nothing works
[image]

Comment: And restarting doesn't fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the utilities folder, open terminal.

Type AssetCacheLocatorUtil and look over the output. There will be a lot. Check the IP address of any caching servers and hunt them down / power them off - observe any other  errors the tool may print.

Then, you might make a brand new user account on the Mac, restart and check if the App Store app behaves differently.

Lastly, the machine needs to be on a network with time server to set the clock and access Apple servers. If you have firewall, slow network, blocked network, this program can get stuck and unable to render any information.

If you're completely out of ideas, power down your Mac and take it ti a network you know to work well - use Safari to browse to a common app - say https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bbedit/id404009241?mt=12 - and see if that works and if you can then use the link from the web page to open the App Store (rather than launching the App Store from your usual method).